# How to rewrite JS function on jQuery properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way to rewrite this function mostly on jQuery, and put var list inside the function to stop it's pollution in .js file.

I'm having difficulties with the upper part, can't figured out how to rewrite properly var's and click event listener to expected result.

Can somebody take a look and help me with that?

```
var d1 = document.getElementsByClassName("div_1");

var $d2 = $(".div_2");

var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  d1[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");

    var content = this.nextElementSibling;

    if (content.style.display === "block") {
        content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        if (this.nextElementSibling.classList.contains("test-class-name") && $d2.is(":empty")) {
          content.style.cssText = "opacity: 0; display: block;";
          // do some stuff
        } else { 
          content.style.display = "block";
        }  
    }                                  
});}
```

// Updated: (if it helps, this is far as I'm get with it for the moment, and stack on the eventlistener part)

```
$(".div1").on("click", function() { 

var $ss = $(".div2");

var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {

$("this").toggleClass("active");}}
```

Comment: Please post what you've tried with jQuery.

Comment: No, do not, forget jQuery exists, it will not solve this issue, this is a conceptual issue, you need to learn about Closures. Welcome to proper javascript. 

"Encapsulate your function in another and return from closure" is the shortest hint-like answer i can give.

Comment: @Dellirium That comment is not constructive at all.  If the OP is using jQuery then they may as well continue to do so, rather than write this specific piece of code in vanilla JS, as you tell them to do.  While *"use jQuery"* is often the wrong advice to give, *"Do not use jQuery"* can be just as bad, if not worse.

Comment: @Archer I should have probably "tagged" user2263572 with the "no don't" since that part of the answer was sort of a knee-jerk rection to his comment, can't edit now. I've got nothing against OP using jQuery, but comment saying "show what you've done with jquery" when the issue is clearly not related to it being jQuery or not won't be fixed by telling the OP to "convert to jQuery" since he is already trying to do that, and cannot, so he asks for help. "how do i draw an elephant" "draw an elephant" sort of thing

Comment: @Dellirium But OP wants to do it in jQuery so it's perfectly normal to ask to see what they've already tried.  I think deleting the comment would be more suitable than tagging the 1st commenter.

Comment: @Archer again, as I said, jQuery is fine, but his issue is converting `vanila > jQuery`  so a comment saying "use jquery` is... well mocking if nothing else, especially since the issue is not a library at all. One more time, the "no don't part" is a comment that was directed towards the first comment above it, since it wouldn't solve a thing

Comment: @Dellirium 1st commenter is basically asking what he's already tried, so we can fix it (which is very, very common).  If OP replied that the question contained everything they'd tried then it would have answered the question - you've simply misunderstood their intent.

Comment: About using not/using jQuery: if it helps it's good. As soon as the scale of a system goes beyond a certain threshold, a terse and uniform syntax is useful. Normally, I avoid it first but jump on it as soon as I feel the urge for it. So, don't depend on it, know your tools but also don't discriminate unreasonably. As always with tool adoption, it's more about yourself than about the tool per se.

Comment: @Archer - heard. Will delete my comments.

Comment: @Archer He is posting what he tried, it is right there, the jQuery code intertwined with vanila js. The connotation of the first comment is, really not a benign "oh so show me what did you try" and is more of a "so, m8, post what you did or we won't help" as it often is the case when people post requests, which even if it was not the case doesn't solve the issue, the question is multifold, one is the conversion the other is the issue with the scoping, and since conversion is an issue that first comment won't solve, and it offers nothing for problem #2, what is the point of asking for it?

Comment: @Dellirium Okay - I've explained.  There is almost zero jQuery in the posted code (only 1 single selector on 1 single line of code, and a reference to it in 1 place later).  You either disagree or don't understand, but this isn't the place for this.  I'm out.

Comment: Updated @user2263572

Answer (score 1):

Not truly sure but this should kinda do it.

```
var d1, d2;

d1 = $(".div_1");
d2 = $(".div_2");

d1.on("click", () => {
  var node, content;

  node = $(this);
  node.toggleClass("active");
  content = node.next();

  if (content.css("display") === "block")
  {
    content.css("display", "none");
  } else {
    if (content.is(".test-class-name") && d2.is(":empty"))
    {
      content.css({ "opacity": 0, "display": "block"});
      // do some stuff
    } else { 
      content.css("display", "block");
    }  
  }
});
```